# ''Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous'' when broadcasting torch Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, broadcast

My objective is to extract the dimensions of a pytorch Tensor, whose indices are not in a given list. I want to use broadcasting to do that like follows:

```
Sim = torch.rand((5, 5))
samples_idx = [0]  # the index of dim that I don't want to extract
a = torch.arange(Sim.size(0)) not in samples_idx
result = Sim[a]
```

I assume `a` would be a Tensor with True/Flase with the dimension of 5.But I get the error `RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous`. Anyone can help me to point out where it goes wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Its unclear what you mean by "extract the dimension", can you provide an example of input and output you want?

Comment: Take the given codes as an example. I want to extract rows 1-4 (without 0) of Tensor `Sim` to form a sub-tensor. The indices of the dimensions that I do not want to extract will be added to the list. It may contain several unconsecutive indices. So I need to acquire a boolean Tensor to show whether I need the corresponding dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding between the concept of "dimension" and "indices". What you want is to filter `Sim` and keep only rows (the 0th dimension) which indices match a given rule.

Here is how you could do that:

```py
Sim = torch.rand((5, 5))
samples_idx = [0]  # the index of dim that I don't want to extract
a = [v for v in range(Sim.size(0)) if v not in samples_idx]
result = Sim[a]
```

`a` is not a boolean Tensor but a list of indices to keep. You then use it to index `Sim` on the 0th dimension (the rows).

`not in` is not an operation that can be broadcasted, you should use a regular Python comprehension list for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarification. It really helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a set containing the desired indices by substracting `samples_idx` from a set containing all indices:

```
>>> Sim = torch.rand(5, 5)
tensor([[0.9069, 0.3323, 0.8358, 0.3738, 0.3516],
        [0.1894, 0.5747, 0.0763, 0.8526, 0.2351],
        [0.0304, 0.7631, 0.3799, 0.9968, 0.6143],
        [0.0647, 0.2307, 0.4061, 0.9648, 0.0212],
        [0.8479, 0.6400, 0.0195, 0.2901, 0.4026]])

>>> samples_idx = [0]
```

The following essentially acts as your `torch.arange not in sample_idx`:

```
>>> idx = set(range(len(Sim))) - set(samples_idx)
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Then perform the indexing with `idx`:

```
>>> Sim[tuple(idx),:]
tensor([[0.1894, 0.5747, 0.0763, 0.8526, 0.2351],
        [0.0304, 0.7631, 0.3799, 0.9968, 0.6143],
        [0.0647, 0.2307, 0.4061, 0.9648, 0.0212],
        [0.8479, 0.6400, 0.0195, 0.2901, 0.4026]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,@Ivan. That helps to realize my function. But I still want to know the reason behind the error of `torch.arange not in sample_idx`. Why can't I use `not in list` to broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bit out of focus, but you could also try using boolean indexing.

```
>>> Sim = torch.rand((5, 5))
tensor([[0.8128, 0.2024, 0.3673, 0.2038, 0.3549],
        [0.4652, 0.4304, 0.4987, 0.2378, 0.2803],
        [0.2227, 0.1466, 0.6736, 0.0929, 0.3635],
        [0.2218, 0.9078, 0.2633, 0.3935, 0.2199],
        [0.7007, 0.9650, 0.4192, 0.4781, 0.9864]])

>>> samples_idx = [0]
>>> a = torch.ones(Sim.size(0))
>>> a[samples_idx] = 0
>>> result = Sim[a.bool(), :]
tensor([[0.4652, 0.4304, 0.4987, 0.2378, 0.2803],
        [0.2227, 0.1466, 0.6736, 0.0929, 0.3635],
        [0.2218, 0.9078, 0.2633, 0.3935, 0.2199],
        [0.7007, 0.9650, 0.4192, 0.4781, 0.9864]])
```

This way you don't have to iterate all the samples_idx list checking the inclusion.